# rabbitmq procession speed issue

Tags: java, spring, rabbitmq

I have a consumer java spring rabbitmq app, when it runs on one node (computer), avg speed is 20 ms/sec, but when I run 2-3 nodes, avg speed is ... 20 ms/sec. Am I correct if say that speed should be multiplied by number of nodes? Thanks

Comment: "run 2-3 nodes" do you mean consumers or rabbitmq nodes? can you add some info? maybe you have this rate because is the publisher rate.

Comment: The you, I mean 2-3 virtual machines, running a java app with spring rabbit consumer configured, let`s say each machine has has concurrentconsumers setting set to 20. Why rate per second is the same as to one such node? Thank you